# How to check if a sequence of letters appear in a string in order?

Tags: java, string

I'm working on a method that gets as an input an array of string and three letters in lower-case.

The method should find words that start with the first letter, and contain the other two letters in the order they were inserted.

If a letter is inserted twice it should appear twice in the word.

For example the word `expected` is a legal word for `(e,e,e)` but the word `seemed` is not legal.

With my following code I get for any input that it's legal, which is wrong.

```
    public static void printWords(String[] vocabulary,
        String firstLetter, String secondLetter, String thirdLetter){

    int counter=0;
    for (String str : vocabulary){
        int index1=0;
        int index2=0;
        String newstr=str;

        if (((str.substring(0,1).equals(firstLetter)))){
        newstr=str.substring(1, str.length());
        if (newstr.contains(secondLetter)){
            index1=str.indexOf(secondLetter);
            newstr=str.substring(index2, str.length());
        }
        if (newstr.contains(thirdLetter)){
            index2=str.indexOf(thirdLetter);

        }

        }
        if (index2>index1)
        {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(str);
        }

    }
    System.out.println("found "+ counter+" words");

}
```

Comment: you should use regex for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much more easier to implement using regex:

```
boolean matches(String word, String letter1, String letter2, String letter3) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    String[] s = new String[] {letter1, letter2, letter3};

    for (String l : s) {
        if (l.length() != 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong input, only 1-char strings are allowed!");
        if (l < "a" || l > "z")
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong input, only lowercase latin letters are allowed!");
    }   

    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(s[0] + ".*" + s[1] + ".*" + s[2] + ".*");

    // will produce a regex like "a.*b.*c.*"

    return regex.matcher(word).matches();
}
```

Comment: pls dont use return true or false, just do: return regex.matcher(input).matches()

Comment: I'm new to Java and I don't know what regex is, can you please explain ?

Comment: @Tam211 regex is a very powerful pattern matching engine for char sequense processing, implemented in most languages. In your case, `a.*b.*c.*` means "starts by a, then any number, even 0, of any chars, then b, then any number if any chars, then c, then any number of any chars again". `.` in pattern means "any char", `*` means "any number of occurrences, even 0".

Comment: if you want to do it perfectly, you should add the "^" at the start of the pattern, which indicates, that the first letter is at the start of your string which you are matching.

Comment: @Dude in JS yes, but in Java `matches()` works against entire input, opposed to `find()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are strictly speaking about the given code (although regex or some other ways are far more elegant and better solutions) it should be:

```
if (((str.substring(0,1).equals(firstLetter)))){
    newstr=str.substring(1, str.length());
    if (newstr.contains(secondLetter)){
        index1=newstr.indexOf(secondLetter) + 1;
        newstr=str.substring(index1 + 1, str.length());
    }
    if (newstr.contains(thirdLetter)){
        index2=newstr.indexOf(thirdLetter) + index1 + 1;

    }
    ....
```